# Set of positive measures and Banach space

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In measure theory i heard recently a statement in my class, which says that the set of all (positive) measures does not make a Banach space ( whereas the set of signed measures makes up a Banach space ).

I know that in order to start the proof you need first to define a norm. Is it arbitrary ? I must then prove it is a norm. Then i would need to prove that every Cauchy sequence of positive measures has a limit in the space, which means that is still a positive measure. 
Must one construct such a sequence ?

Can somebody give me some hints ?

Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The set of positive measures isn't even a vector space.

Answer (score 1):

For the set if signed measures (on a sigma-algebra $\mathcal F$ on a set $\Omega$) we can use the "total variation" norm.

$$
\|\sigma\|_{TV} = \sigma(P)-\sigma(N)
$$
where $P$ is the positive set, $N$ is the negative set:
$$
N \cup P = \Omega,\qquad N \cap P = \varnothing
\\
\sigma(A) \ge 0\qquad\text{for all } A \subseteq P
\\
\sigma(A) \le 0\qquad\text{for all } A \subseteq N
$$
I leave it to you to show the space of signed measures is complete in this norm.